# Difficulty displaying "login" and "main" forms correctly

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, message-loop

I have a WinForms application, with a login form and main form. The login form contains two textboxes for the user to enter credentials, an OK button, and a Cancel button. The following code is the event handler for the OK button:

```
        private void button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (authenticated())
            {
                this.Close();
                Application.Run(new MainWindow());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentials", "Retail POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }    
        }
```

The problem with this is that it keeps the login dialog when the main form opens. I have tried to accomplish the desired behaviour by showing the login form as a modal dialog by calling `ShowDialog()` from `Program.cs`, but this has not achieved the desired behaviour.

Note that the main form has an option to log out. That is, it should remove the main form and display the login form again.

Program.cs code:

```
static void Main()
{
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This produces an error, saying a second message loop cannot be started.

Comment: You have code written on main form to show login form?  Can you share the code of program.cs file?

Comment: No, `Program.cs` calls up the login form. I will add the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide your fist from. You can do it with `this.Hide()`

Be careful where you position `this.Hide()`.

If you are using `mainForm.Show();` you can place it before or after it, but if using `mainForm.ShowDialog();` you can place it only before it since `ShowDialog()` stops code from executing until form which called this method is closed.

From `program.cs` you start your application with `Application.Run(YourMainForm)`

Since you want your `LoginForm` to be first when you open app you should create it inside `Program.cs` and pass it inside `Application.Run()` like this:

```
...
LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
...
Application.Run(lf);
```

Now we have `LoginForm` displayed. We can not close it since our application will close (since it is main form)

So when user login and press button and succeed, we hide our main form and show other we want like this:

```
private void button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (authenticated())
    {
        MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
        mw.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentials", "Retail POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Now we have our `MainForm` displayed, and login hidden.

Since you want to make so user can log off, you can do it two ways:

First is when user press button, we do this:

```
LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
lf.Show();
this.Close(); //We assume that button is placed in your main form
```

This way we again display Login Form (at this point we have 2 login forms in memory, main one and new one which is a waste of memory) and there user can login again. This way every time user logs out you will have one more `LoginForm` in memory which is very bad.

Other efficient way is that inside `Program.cs` file we do not create `LoginForm` instance inside `Main()` function, but outside and mark it as `public static`

It would look like this:

```
Program.cs

...
static class Program
{
    ...
    public static LoginForm mainForm;

    static void Main()
    {
        ....
        mainForm = new LoginForm();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
    }
}
```

Now when we have this and user press `Logout` in your `MainWindow` you do not need to create new instance of `LoginForm` but you can just `Show()` existing (main) one with `Program.mainForm.Show()`

Comment: What about if I use `Application.Run(new MainForm());` ?